# Join and fetch just some properties not all the collection with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Consedireing this query :

```
 @Query("select c from Contact c "
         + " join fetch c.abonnements ab ")
 Set<Contact > findServiceNotifContactFtech();
```

How to get just two or one property from the collection `abonnements` in the join clause because with `fetch c.abonnements` hibernate **fetch** me all properties and i got 30 properties in the type of `abonnements`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you feel this really worthwhile, then see below but note the comment about it rarely being worthwhile.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html

> 19.1.7. Using lazy property fetching
>
> Hibernate3 supports the lazy fetching of individual properties. This
>   optimization technique is also known as fetch groups. **Please note
>   that this is mostly a marketing feature; optimizing row reads is much
>   more important than optimization of column reads. However, only
>   loading some properties of a class could be useful in extreme cases.**
>   For example, when legacy tables have hundreds of columns and the data
>   model cannot be improved.
>
> To enable lazy property loading, set the lazy attribute on your
>   particular property mappings:
>
> Lazy property loading requires buildtime bytecode instrumentation. If
>   your persistent classes are not enhanced, Hibernate will ignore lazy
>   property settings and return to immediate fetching.
>
> A different way of avoiding unnecessary column reads, at least for
>   read-only transactions, is to use the projection features of HQL or
>   Criteria queries. This avoids the need for buildtime bytecode
>   processing and is certainly a preferred solution.
>
> You can force the usual eager fetching of properties using fetch all
>   properties in HQL.

Essentially then, as noted in the documentation, Lazy Fetch of properties can be enabled but will be ignored at run-time unless you have 'enhanced' your classes at build time using the Ant Task referenced in the documentation. If your classes  are not instrumented then property level lazy loading will be silently ignored. This is  line with the JPA specification which does not mandate that lazy loading of individual properties should be supported:

http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1423670601_31b0b4beeddadd49047c08d63a9ad933

See 11.1.16

> The LAZY strategy is a **hint** to the persistence provider runtime
>   that data should be fetched lazily when it is first accessed. The
>   implementation is permitted to eagerly fetch data for which the LAZY
>   strategy hint has been specified

Comment: the Ant Task is necessary ? i use maven so we can use them both ?

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to select `Abonnement` properties and map them to DTO (e.g. MyDTO), you just have to turn the query upside-down:

```
@Query("select new my.package.MyDTO(c, ab.prop1, ab.prop2) from Abonnements a join a.contact c")
Set<MyDTO> findMyDTO();
```

Where MyDTO is like:

```
public MyDTO {
    private final Contact contact;
    private final String prop1;
    private final String prop2;

    public MyDTO(Contact contact, String prop1, String prop2) {
        this.contact= contact;
        this.prop1 = prop1;
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }

    //getters
}
```

The only problem is that you will get more `Contact` entries for each `Abonnnment` child entry.

Comment: that give me more idea but i can't use it in my case because i don't select only one collection ... and the problem of more `Contact` i want to handle it in past cases but i cant.

Comment: but there is a problem - Concat is entity in DTO object. And what about if I need to fetch Collection<DTO>?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want your projection to fit the properties you need in your DTOs, I'd suggest you give [blaze-persistence](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence) entity-views a chance. You're DTOs would then look like this:

```
@EntityView(Contact.class)
public interface MyDTO {

  @IdMapping
  Integer getId();

  // You can have any JPQL expression here
  @Mapping("firstname")
  String getFirstname();

  // property name is the default mapping
  String getLastname();

  Set<AbonnementDTO> getAbonnements();

}

@EntityView(Abonnement.class)
public interface AbonnementDTO {

  @IdMapping
  Integer getId();

  String getProp1();

}
```

The use site looks like this

```
@Inject
EntityManager em;
@Inject
CriteriaBuilderFactory cbf;
@Inject
EntityViewManager evm;

public void test() {
  CriteriaBuilder<Contact> cb = cbf.create(em, Contact.class);
  List<ContactDTO> result = evm.applySetting(EntityViewSetting.create(ContactDTO.class), cb)
      .getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT o.property1, o.property2 FROM EntityA o WHERE ....`, the result will be a `List<Object[2]>`, where the array contents will contain the values.

Comment: but i want property from the entity in the join clause not in the from clause ? it's the same ?

Comment: Sure, they are orthogonal - what you have in the SELECT just needs to refer to something from the FROM/JOIN clauses.

Comment: but i have `fetch` and i have to return a `contact`

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting select firstname,lastname from contacts mean then

```
 @Query("select c.firstname,c.lastname from Contact c "
         + " join fetch c.abonnements ab ")
 Set<Contact > findServiceNotifContactFtech();
```

Comment: but i want property from the entity in the join clause not in the from clause ? it's the same ?

Comment: but i have `fetch` and i have to return a `contact`